# Multiple services with Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I have 3 different api services like

1st class

```
@GET("https://api.myapi")
```

2nd class

```
@GET("https://openapi.myapi")
```

3rd class

```
@GET("https://closedapi.myapi")
```

Retrofit need base url, but these 3 services have different beginning of url and I was trying to make base url as `https://` and removed `https://` from these 3x `@GET` but it doesn't work (I got `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL host: ""`)

```
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .baseUrl("https://") <- it doesn't work
            .build()
    }
```

What could be wrong and how handle it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use separate instances of `Retrofit` for each backend (i.e. base URL) and then differentiate them using Dagger qualifiers.

```kotlin
// These should also have @Target and @Retention specified, but I omitted them for clarity.
@Qualifier annotation class ApiRetrofit
@Qualifier annotation class OpenApiRetrofit
@Qualifier annotation class ClosedApiRetrofit

@Module
object DaggerModule {

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  @ApiRetrofit
  fun apiRetrofit(baseOkHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
      .baseUrl("https://api.myapi")
      .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
      .client(baseOkHttpClient)
      .build()
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  @OpenApiRetrofit
  fun openApiRetrofit(baseOkHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
      .baseUrl("https://openapi.myapi")
      .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
      .client(baseOkHttpClient)
      .build()
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  @ClosedApiRetrofit
  fun closedApiRetrofit(baseOkHttpClient: OkHttpClient, moshi: Moshi): Retrofit {
    // You can customize per-backend behavior, e.g. call timeouts, authentication, 
    // interceptors, serialization library, etc.
    val customizedOkHttpClient = baseOkHttpClient.newBuilder()
      .authenticator(...)
      .addInterceptor(...)
      .build()
    return Retrofit.Builder()
      .baseUrl("https://closedapi.myapi")
      .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
      .client(customizedOkHttpClient)
      .build()
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  fun apiService(@ApiRetrofit retrofit: Retrofit): ApiService = retrofit.create()

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  fun openApiService(@OpenApiRetrofit retrofit: Retrofit): OpenApiService = retrofit.create()

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  fun closedApiService(@ClosedApiRetrofit retrofit: Retrofit): ClosedApiService = retrofit.create()
}
```